# Render a table with selected keys from a JSON via $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to display a table in a HTML File. I use jQuery and the $.getJSON function. If use the function from the jquery documentation I just get a primary key but not the information inside it. It just outputs

ID: object Object.

How can I pick specific keys from the JSON to display them.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will automatically parse the JSON into a JS object, which may be unexpected. Logging the object to the console will display the object, however certain JS functions, such as alert(), can only display strings.

If you are wanting to display the object value/pair, you will need to access it like an ordinary JS object, for example data.ListOfWhatever. If you are wanting to display it as a string, simply use JSON.stringify()

Hopefully that helps, if not, feel free to reply with some of the code and I can help!